# Multiple US Visas

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I have travelled to the US on B1/B2 visa and later on an F-1 visa. Due to a personal emergency I had to leave midway in the program while I was on an F-1 visa. But I'd informed the graduate office, my professor and completed the necessary formalities.

Will I face an issue if I were to travel to the US again. Do I need to reapply for a US visa since I already have a B1/B2 visa which is still valid?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  If your visa B1/B2 is still valid why would you need to reapply for a visa to enter the country?  F visa might be a different story but you may want to clarify.

Comment: @Karlson I wanted to know if an issuance of F-1 visa automatically invalidates the B1/B2 visa.  I dont want to have any issues at the port of entry because of this.

Comment: There is no reason why it should but a consulate would be able to give you a definite answer

Answer (score 7):

I didnt have any issues at the port of entry, it was pretty smooth. He just asked my purpose of travel and stamped me.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your B Visa or F Visa have been revoked and stamped as such as [documented here](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/87513.pdf) you should still be able to enter US if one or the other Visa is still valid.

One thing that I can't find yet is whether or not obtaining of F visa supersedes B visa but I don't think it should.

**EDIT**

On the subject of F visa superseding and invalidating the B visa you can obtain this information at the local consulate.

Comment: Your link is now broken. :-(

Comment: Yeah...  Not sure where it was.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter on a B1/B2 visa they can only give you a duration of stay of 6 months or less. To resume F1 status and be able to stay as long as your program lasts, you need to enter on an F1 visa.