# Can I enter a different schengen country before I enter the country of my student residence permit?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have been accepted for a Masters degree in Finland. Because of this, I have already applied for the Finnish Residence Permit starting 1st August 2015. However, I wanted to visit Germany for a month before I start my master's study. I have been invited by a family friend for a month to travel and celebrate their grandparent's 50th anniversary.

When inquired about it at the Finnish embassy they mentioned that I cannot go to any other Schengen country before 1st August as I need to first enter Finland using my residence permit and then can go to any Schengen country. I also cannot apply for a separate German Schengen visa from 1st July 2015 to 31st July 2015 as one cannot hold two Schengen visas at the same time.

My doubt revolves around the last statement. Since the dates for my application to German Schengen visa doesn't overlap the Finland Residence permit dates, can I still apply for German tourist visa from 1st July to 31st July 2015? Also can I travel to Finland from Germany?

Comment: What does "I, PR, 25F" mean?

Comment: Thats just my name (short form), 25 yrs old, Female

Comment: @PukhrajR Immaterial to your request...

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17122/which-visa-will-i-be-entering-under

Comment: The residence permit is not a Schengen visa and does not overlap, I don't see how it could be a problem. Even entering through another country for transit should generally be possible (although I must admit I don't know exactly how all this works in Finland). The main issue is that you will need to pick up the permit wherever the Finnish embassy decides to make it available, probably in your current country of residence, so you might have to leave the Schengen area and travel half-way around the world instead of going directly from Germany to Finland.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Not a duplicate (though one might think so looking only at the title). The OP here wants to on vacation elsewhere in the Schengen area _before_ the start date of her residence permit, and asks whether the rules allow the destination country of the vacation trip to issue a short-stay visa for it.